# Roslyn analyzer, converted from C# to F#

Tags: f#, roslyn

I'm learning F# and for an exercise, I took a [roslyn analyzer in C#](https://github.com/mykolav/use-named-arguments/tree/dbc3c26734f3f325df3ca7799f743ab0d54a33b1) and ported it [to F#](https://github.com/mykolav/use-named-args-fs/tree/80aa1184aa7b66c0199feb26656ff5cbbfb82b19).

In the excerpt below the `GetParameterInfo` function:

- takes in `ArgumentSyntax` which describes an argument passed to a
  `C#` method at an invocation site.
- And finds the corresponding `IParameterSymbol` which describes the method's parameter at the point in code where the method is defined.

Here it is:

```
module UseNamedArgs.ParameterInfo

open System
open System.Collections.Immutable
open Microsoft.CodeAnalysis
open Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax
open UseNamedArgs.CSharpAdapters
open UseNamedArgs.MaybeBuilder

type ParameterInfo = {
    MethodOrProperty : ISymbol;
    Parameter : IParameterSymbol }

type ISymbol with
    member symbol.GetParameters() =
        match symbol with
        | :? IMethodSymbol as s   -> s.Parameters
        | :? IPropertySymbol as s -> s.Parameters
        | _                       -> ImmutableArray<IParameterSymbol>.Empty
        |> Seq.toList

/// <summary>
/// To be able to convert positional arguments to named we need to find
/// corresponding <see cref="IParameterSymbol" /> for each argument.
/// </summary>
type SemanticModel with
    member sema.GetParameterInfo (argument: ArgumentSyntax) =
        maybe {
            let argList = argument.Parent :?> ArgumentListSyntax
            let exprSyntax = argList.Parent  :?> ExpressionSyntax
            let methodOrProperty = sema.GetSymbolInfo(exprSyntax).Symbol
            let! parameters = methodOrProperty.GetParameters() |> Option.ofList
            if isNull argument.NameColon then
                // A positional argument.
                match argList.Arguments.IndexOf(argument) with
                | index when index >= 0 && index < parameters.Length -> 
                    return { MethodOrProperty = methodOrProperty;
                             Parameter = parameters.[index] }
                | index when index >= parameters.Length 
                             && parameters.[parameters.Length - 1].IsParams ->
                    return { MethodOrProperty = methodOrProperty;
                             Parameter = parameters.[parameters.Length - 1] }
                | _ -> return! None
            else 
                // Potentially, this is a named argument.
                let! name = argument.NameColon.Name |> Option.ofObj
                let! nameText = name.Identifier.ValueText |> Option.ofObj
                // Yes, it's a named argument.
                let! parameter = parameters |> Seq.tryFind (fun param -> 
                    String.Equals(param.Name, 
                                  nameText, 
                                  StringComparison.Ordinal))

                return { MethodOrProperty = methodOrProperty;
                         Parameter = parameter }
}
```

- *The original C# code of this snippet was adapted from
  [CSharpEssentials](https://github.com/DustinCampbell/CSharpEssentials/blob/master/Source/CSharpEssentials/Extensions.cs)*
- *The `maybe` computational expression is defined in
  [MaybeBuilder](https://github.com/mykolav/use-named-args-fs/blob/588487895eb1af4af6b4886620118102c2d2d62d/UseNamedArgs/Support/MaybeBuilder.fs)
  — but it's likely pretty much what you'd expect a `maybe` to be.*

How can I change the code so it'll be more idiomatic F#?
And is it even anywhere in the ballpark of idiomatic F#?

Answer (score 1):

I feel we can traverse the Roslyn AST but it's chatty and boring for write with a lot of non aspect code fragment :(

My suggestion for reference is my experimental project "F# Active pattern library for Roslyn Compiler Platform" can ease for use Roslyn AST directly F# pattern matching syntax.

https://github.com/kekyo/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ActivePatterns